# Is it possible to have nested functions, without having closures, in a lexically scoped language which has first class functions?

Tags: scope, closures

> A closure is a record storing a function, together with an
>   environment: A mapping associating each free variable of the function
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope)
>   with the value or reference to which the name was bound when the
>   closure was created. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)))

Here is what I understand. A function can access to 3 types of variables (Let's assume JavaScript):

1. **Parameters:** The parameters of a function.
2. **Local variables:** The variables defined inside of a function. (but not the variables defined in a nested function. That is, a function cannot access variables defined in another function, where this another function is defined inside the function we are talking about)
3. **Free variables:** The variables defined outside of the function. That is, the function can access the variables defined in the function which surrounds our function, and the variables defined in the function which surrounds the function that surround our function, etc.

Of these 3 types, the values of the variables of type 1 and 2 are well known at the time a function is called. However, the variables of type 3 can have any value at the time a function is called. To the best of my knowledge, this is a property of dynamically scoped languages. That is, AFAIK, in lexically scoped languages, we cannot have such situation.

That's where a closure comes into scene. A closure *binds* the free variables of a function. Hence, there isn't any variable which doesn't have a well known value, at the time a function is called.

So, my question is the following:

> Are closures a must have in lexically scoped languages, which allow
>   nested functions and which have first class functions?

To me, it seems like so. Because if nested first class functions are allowed in a language without having closures, then this means that the free variables will have non-deterministic values at the time a function is called. But AFAIK, having non-deterministic values is a property of *dynamically scoped* languages. Hence, I claim:

> If a language claims to be lexically scoped, and if a language allows
>   nested first class functions, then, by definition, every function in
>   that language is (must be) a closure.

I am correct in this?

Comment: Define "first class function".  The definition will determine whether closures are necessary ... in some cases ... to implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your conclusion is true.

```
function outer1() {
  const foo = 42;

  function inner1() {};
}
```

In this case, `inner1` is not a closure, but it is a nested function. It simply doesn't use any identifiers from the surrounding scope.

```
function outer2() {
  const foo = 42;

  function inner2() { return foo; };

  return inner2();
}
```

Here, `inner2` *does* use `foo`, but `inner2` never leaves the scope of `outer2`, and thus doesn't "close over" its surrounding environment. It is not a closure.

```
function outer3() {
  const foo = 42;

  function inner3() { return 23; };

  return inner3;
}
```

Here, `inner3` *does* leave the scope of `outer3`, but it doesn't use any free variables. Again, not a closure.

```
function outer4() {
  const foo = 42;

  function inner4() { return foo; };

  return inner4;
}
```

Only `inner4` is actually a closure: it leaves the scope of `outer4` and closes over its environment and "takes it with it".

So, as you can see, it is perfectly possible to have nested functions which aren't closures in a lexically scoped language, as long as at least one of the following is true:

1. the nested function has no access to the surrounding environment
2. the nested function does not leave the scope of the surrounding environment

To be fair, I can't think of a language that has those restrictions, though. But there *are* similar restrictions on by-ref captured variables in C++ lambdas, I think. A C++ lambda that captures a variable by-reference can either not use that variable or not leave the scope. If it does both, the result is undefined behavior (and will most likely result in an illegal memory access).

Comment: +1 C++ is a good example of muddying the waters. A `[&]` lambda can leave the scope so that other functions can call it and is a true lexical closure in that sense, but it can't be used beyond the lifetime of the referenced objects, so it's also kind of dynamically scoped. Another question is whether closures-by-copy in a mutable language qualify as closures, since they capture values, not variables (e.g. `[=]` lambdas in C++, or nested classes in Java).

Comment: `inner1` would still _not_ be a closure, even if it had used identifiers from outer scopes, right? Because there is no way to access `inner1` from the outer scopes.

Comment: @Utku: Yes. I chose to start with the "most obvious" example first. You will notice that I listed two conditions at the end, so two examples would have sufficed. `inner1` is an example that satisfies *both* conditions, `inner2` and `inner3` relax those restrictions to satisfy only one of them, and only `inner4` violates both.

Comment: While I agree with this analysis, `inner4` as illustrated could easily be optimized to not close over `foo`, as it is a constant (not just that it is const). Depicting `foo` as a parameter of the outer function, or a local computed from some such  parameter would not be optimizable like that.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the second example: even though inner2 does not leave the scope of outer2, it does resolve its free variable using the environment in which it is defined. I thought this is sufficient to consider the inner function a closure. What happens if you change your fourth example and put the `return inner4` inside a branch of an `if` statement, and make the condition of the `if` depend on some argument of the outer function. In this case, would `inner4` still be a closure? In other words, in my (maybe wrong?) intuition being a closure is a static property, not a dynamic one.